# Referencing the HeaderText of a TemplateField by text value rather than by index

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

Server side I want to use the HeaderText from a Templatefield from a DetailsView in a String which is to be returned as a text value for a label which is a grandchild of the Templatefield. How do I reference the HeaderText "Care Plan Intent" explicitly in the code behind by name rather than using an index, and then use it in a string to replace the text value for the label which is an Eval of a sql datasource if the value does not meet certain crieria.
For instance in the example below, if the value of Eval("CarePlanIntent") is ok then all well and good, otherwise I want to replace it with something like "Either Care Plan Intent has not been entered or it does not meet the set criteria".

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvTest">
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Care Plan Intent:">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label skinid="tablabelblack" id="lblIntent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CarePlanIntent") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do this:

```
var field = dvText.Fields.First(i => i.HeaderText == "Care Plan Intent:");
var lbl = (Label)field.FindControl("lblIntent");

if (lbl.Text == "Y")
  lbl.Text = "New Text";
```

Something like that.... I may have some of the properties or methods wrong; but it should be something like that.

Comment: Sorry but our set up is a bit ancient and we don't have LINQ. Is there something compatibale with .net 2.0 to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, you can get the label inside the details view instead of finding the proper template field by header text.

```
Dim lblIntent As Label = CType(dvTest.FindControl("lblIntent"), Label)
If lblIntent.Text <> "Your Condition" Then
    lblIntent.Text = "Some New Text"
End If
```

Comment: Does this just nor return the label value rather than the HeaderText of the label's Templatefield?

Comment: @PaulStevens Sorry, I misread some parts of your question. However, what specifically do you mean by referencing the TemplateField by name? As in by the header text? If so, that would be redundant no? You would be getting the header text by using the same text. You already know the header text at that point. If by another identifier, then I believe there is only by index. Sorry if I am misunderstanding something.